# Grails: PrototypeJS lib adding an extra underscore (_) parameter and doubling up all parameters

Tags: grails, prototypejs

I'm using `Grails 2.3.3` with prototype as my js library.

I have an ajax call that sends over some parameters to the server that are to be bound to an object.
The ajax call that is generated always appends `&_:` at the end of my parameter list. So instead of having this map: `[name:bar, action:save, controller:foo]` I get `[name:bar, _:, action:save, controller:foo]` (note the `_:`)

When I try to do
`foo.properties = params`
I get the following error (on `foo.errors`):

```
grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 1 errors
Error in object 'com.mypackage.Foo': codes []; arguments []; default message [String index out of range: 2]
End of error dump
```

If I remove the appended `_` key from the parameter map (with `params.remove('_')`) it no longer has errors.

The problem here is that this worked fine on my app with Grails version 1.3.9 but it stopped working once I made the upgrade to 2.3.3.

---

After upgrading prototype library, the parameters are now doubled up.

Comment: which version of PrototypeJS?, 1.7.1 is the latest

Comment: Updating prototype works but it still doesn't tell me why would Grails 2.3.3 behave differently when compared to Grails 1.3.9 on this matter.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grails - so here is a few theories. Grails updated(downgraded) Prototype with the upgrade, old Grails might have ignored that extra parameter, or a combination of both. I know I have seen that exact parameter before and upgrading fixed it, along with many other weirdness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old but I somehow keep coming back to this question every time this thing happens.

Like Geek Num 88 said, updating PrototypeJS works to solve the extra underscore parameter that is sent to the server.

The second problem is happening because of a mistake in `PrototypeProvider.groovy`, see [this pull request on github](https://github.com/gpc/grails-prototype/pull/6/files).

You'll have to find your `PrototypeProvider.groovy` class which is usually under

```
<grails_home>/projects/<your_project>/plugins/prototype-1.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/prototype/PrototypeProvider.groovy
```

or

```
<your project source directory>/target/plugins/prototype-1.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/prototype/PrototypeProvider.groovy
```